# How could I make the navigation menu open once the user hovers over it using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a navigation menu with React and TailWindcss, which should open only when a user hover over it. I've tried different approaches but never worked out and what remaining is to make the menu opens but it never did.

I've 3 components for this task:

MenuItem component:

```
'use client';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FaBars } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { HiChevronDown } from 'react-icons/hi';

interface MenuItemProps {
  label: string;
  link: string;
  onMouseEnter?: () => void;
  onMouseLeave?: () => void;
  onClick?: () => void;
}

const MenuItem: React.FC<MenuItemProps> = ({
  label,
  onMouseEnter,
  onMouseLeave,
  onClick,
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
    if (onMouseEnter) {
      onMouseEnter();
    }
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
    if (onMouseLeave) {
      onMouseLeave();
    }
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <div
        className="px-6 py-3 hover:bg-neutral-100 hover:rounded-xl transition font-semibold cursor-pointer"
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <span className="flex items-center">
          {label}{' '}
          <HiChevronDown
            className={`ml-1 ${isOpen ? 'transform rotate-180' : ''}`}
            style={{ marginTop: '0.125rem' }}
          />
        </span>
        {isOpen && (
          <ul className="pl-6 mt-2">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            {/* Add more menu items here */}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

UserMenu component:

```
'use client';

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlineMenu } from "react-icons/ai";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import MenuItem from "./menuItem";

interface UserMenuProps {
  onClick?: () => void;
  label: string;
  link: string;
}

const UserMenu: React.FC<UserMenuProps> = ({ onClick, label, link }) => {
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setMenuIsOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative items-center gap-7">
      <div>
        <div onClick={handleToggle}>
          <MenuItem label={label} onClick={onClick} link={""} />
        </div>
        {menuIsOpen && (
          <ul className="pl-6 mt-2">
            <li>
              <a href={link}>{label}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserMenu;
```

NavBar component:

```
'use client';

import React, { ReactElement, useState } from 'react';
import { FaArrowDown } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useCallback } from 'react';

import Container from '../contanier';
import Logo from './logo';
import MenuItem from './menuItem';
import UserMenu from './userMenu';

interface MegaMenuItemProps{
  label: string,
  link: string,
  children: ReactElement
}

const MegaMenuItem = ({ label, link, children }) => {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };
  const toggleOpen = useCallback(() => {
    setIsHovered((value) => !value);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="relative"
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      <UserMenu label={label} link={link} onClick={toggleOpen} />
      {isHovered && (
        <div className="absolute left-0 top-full pl-2 mt-1 bg-white shadow-md">
          <MenuItem label={'label'} link={'/'}/>
          <MenuItem label={'label'} link={'/'}/>
          <MenuItem label={'label'} link={'/'}/>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <div className="flex flex-auto bg-white sticky items-center justify-between gap-7 md:gap-1 p-5">
          <Logo />
          <div>
            <MegaMenuItem label="product" link="/">
            </MegaMenuItem>
          </div>
          <div className="space-x-4">
            <button className="font-semibold bg-amber-400 rounded-full p-3 justify-center text-white hover:bg-amber-600 ">
              <a href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
            </button>
            <button className="font-semibold bg-white rounded-full p-3 justify-center text-amber-600 hover:bg-amber-400 hover:text-white hover:shadow-sm">
              <a href="/login">Log In</a>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

The main component here is NavBar component as you can see.

This is my first week of learning React & Next so expect the code to look bad and apperciate any learning advice. Thanks in advance!

I've tried everything from ChatGpt, YT videos, and even copying Github reporistroes and the best I could get is having the menu open all the time and it didn't even close so I prefered to have it closed and then try to make it open once the user hover/open it.

Comment: What is the problem right now? Does the menu appear in the DOM?

Comment: It appears in the DOM but it doesn't open for some reason.

Comment: Try replacing `top-full` with `top-0`

Comment: Just tried it. No difference.